# Generate Class Parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the system in asp.net C#, and I have 3 environment for system:

1. Development Environment
2. Homologate Environment
3. Production Environment

and I have an class that saved all necessary parameters in my system (connection strings, image folders, files folders), but these parameters are different in 3 cases.

I wanted to create a factory of parameters depending on the environment that I'm using.

Somebody knows an pattern to use this or some example?

Comment: You should use a configuration file/database to store your environment specific settings.

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio 2010? Then you should use Web.config transforms.

Comment: And what does "homologate environment" mean? I looked up "homologate", but don't see how that relates to an environment.

Comment: is an environment for my bosses approve the change made ​​to the system

Comment: is possoble to create an factory class with a lot of parameter and instantiate a determined class when system is accessed?

Answer (score 2):

usually I use web.config transformations for this:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465318.aspx

also you might want to have a look into a visual studio plugin that helps with this process (slow cheetah):

- http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/69023d00-a4f9-4a34-a6cd-7e854ba318b5

Comment: is possoble to create an factory class with a lot of parameter and instantiate a determined class when system is accessed?

Comment: it is possible, but that means you have more code to maintain. With transformations, you only have to look after a few config files

Answer (score 0):

I usually solve this by having a web.config appSetting in which I can specify the deployment type (dev, stage, live). At runtime I can then programatically decide what to do.